# Lie-Algebra valued differential forms in Mathematica (non-abelian)

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematica

I am trying to implement wedge product of Lie-algebra valued differential forms in the non-abelian case. Concretely, I am intereste in 1- and 2-forms, that is, $A$ and $F$. Is there a way of doing this? I tried using the normal definitions for tensors but the wedge product of $A$ with itself gives me zero.

Alternatively, is there a package to do this?

Comment: Isn't the wedge product anti-symmetric and this implies that the wedge product of anything with itself is zero?

Comment: I am working in non-abelian case. This does not hold.